# Can't set bool to True

Tags: python, django, deployment, pythonanywhere

I just deployed my code to a live environment (PythonAnywhere) and get an exception when I try to change the field of a model:

```
paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I get a `'bool' object is not subscriptable` when I try to

```
payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find(payment_id)
response = payment.execute({"payer_id": payer_id})
trans = Transaction.objects.get(paypal_id=payment_id)
if response:
  trans.paid = True # <--- Here
  trans.save()
```

The traceback

```
File "/home/my/proj/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/my/proj/api/views/paypal.py" in success
  15.         paypal.finish_payment(payment_id, payer_id)
File "/home/my/proj/api/payment_processors/paypal_processor.py" in finish_payment
  54.             trans.paid = True

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/paypal/success
Exception Value: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: the actual error is happening elsewhere. Are you overriding any local/context variable names ? Also, are you familiar with `pdb` ?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I know pdb.

Comment: @karthikr No I am not overriding a local/context variable.

Comment: You've made code changes without reloading your web app, so the line numbers for the source of the error are incorrect. Reload your web app and do it again to see the actual line where the error is occurring.